# Getting an ArrayFormula #N/A error

Tags: vlookup

I'm importing data into my first sheet to match rows in a second sheet (which is connected to a JotForm feed).

This formula returns an `#N/A` error when there is no match in the second sheet. I would love the cells to remain blank instead...

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B2:B), vlookup(B2:B, 
{'Reg Forms'!C2:C, 'Reg Forms'!A2:L}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}, 0),))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I replaced it with this... Seems to work? Let me know if you agree...


=ArrayFormula(IF(ISNA(vlookup(B2:B, {'Reg Forms'!C2:C, 'Reg Forms'!A2:L}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}, 0)),"",vlookup(B2:B, {'Reg Forms'!C2:C, 'Reg Forms'!A2:L}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}, 0)))

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself. (Ideally, also include an explanation of *why* you think it works.)